# Need help figuring out the difference between two SQL queries from the sqlzoo self join quiz

Tags: sql

I was taking this quiz:

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join_Quiz

and I don't really understand why one of the options for question 2 is correct and the other is incorrect.

Question 2 states:

2. Select the code that shows the stops that are on route.num '2A' which can be reached with one bus from Haymarket?

The correct answer is the last option:

```
select s2.id, s2.name, r2.company, r2.num
from stops s1, stops s2, route r1, route r2
where s1.name='Haymarket' and s1.id=r1.stop
and r1.company=r2.company and r1.num=r2.num
and r2.stop=s2.id and r2.num='2A'
```

but the first option, which is incorrect, is this:

```
select s2.id, s2.name, r2.company, r2.num
from stops s1, stops s2, route r1, route r2
where s1.name='Haymarket' and s1.id=r1.stop
and r1.company=r2.company and r1.num=r2.num
and r2.stop=s2.id and r1.num='2A'
```

It seems that the only difference between these 2 queries is the correct answer has r2.num='2A' whereas the incorrect answer has r1.num='2A'. However since both queries specify r1.num=r2.num, shouldn't both answers be correct?

Comment: Technically, yes.  But both are terrible because they're using implicit `JOIN` syntax, which was deprecated [**over 25 years ago**](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).  If this site is actually teaching SQL using this ancient standard, I question the legitimacy of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It seems that Sqlzoo sometimes have errors on the quizzes. And as proof, they give the exact same results when executed on the site. (With the top row id being 173 and the bottom row id also being 173)